# JQuery Select Option with multiple labels

Tags: jquery

I'm stuck here. How do I make this work? I have two select options and I need two separate labels to be set. The problem is when I add a value to the first select, it populates both labels. I need select 1 to label416 and select 2 to label418.

Select 1

```
<select id="selectMove" name="bowelMovements" style="width: 125px">
                            <option>--Select--</option>
                            <option>Normal</option>
                            <option>Constipation</option>
                            <option>Diarrhea</option>
                        </select>
                        <script type="text/javascript">
                            $("select")
                              .change(function () {
                                  var str = "";
                                  $("select option:selected").each(function () {
                                      str += $(this).text() + " ";
                                  });
                                  $('#<%=Label414.ClientID%>').text(str);
                              })
                              .trigger("change");
                        </script>
```

Select 2

```
<select name="bowelMoves" multiple="multiple" style="width: 125px">
                            <option>1 Quadrant</option>
                            <option>2 Quadrant</option>
                            <option>Hypo</option>
                            <option>Hyper</option>
                            <option>Normal</option>
                        </select>
                        <script type="text/javascript">
                            $("select")
                              .change(function () {
                                  var str = "";
                                  $("select option:selected").each(function () {
                                      str += $(this).text() + ", ";
                                  });
                                  $('#<%=Label418.ClientID%>').text(str);
                              })
                              .trigger("change");
                        </script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use `$("select")` you tell jquery to select **every** `<select>` element in the page (and not a specific one).

If you want to select a specific element you should be more specific.

Your first `<select>` element has `id="selectMove"`, so you can use that id:

```
$("#selectMove").change(function () {
```

Your second `<select>` element doesn't have an id, but it has the `name` attribute, so you can use it:

```
$("select[name='bowelMoves']").change(function () {
```

Comment: pure genius... thank you. You saved me a massive headache.

Comment: Now I seem to be having problems. It was working, but for some reason it is not. Label414 works, but label418 is 414 + 418 values.

Answer (score 1):

Solved my problem by reading...

http://api.jquery.com/val/

```
    <script>
function displayVals() {
  var singleValues = $( "#single" ).val();
  var multipleValues = $( "#multiple" ).val() || [];
  // When using jQuery 3:
  // var multipleValues = $( "#multiple" ).val();
  $( "p" ).html( "<b>Single:</b> " + singleValues +
    " <b>Multiple:</b> " + multipleValues.join( ", " ) );
}

$( "select" ).change( displayVals );
displayVals();
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Label414 is working. Label418 is 414 + 418.

Bowel Movements:  Normal 
Last Bowel Movement:
Bowel Sounds:  Normal, 1 Quadrant, Hypo,

Bowel Sounds should be NORMAL plus the other two...

```
 <select id="selectMove" name="selectMove" style="width: 125px">
                            <option>--Select--</option>
                            <option>Normal</option>
                            <option>Constipation</option>
                            <option>Diarrhea</option>
                        </select>
                        <script type="text/javascript">
                            $("#selectMove")
                              .change(function () {
                                  var str1 = "";
                                  $("select option:selected").each(function () {
                                      str1 += $(this).text() + " ";
                                  });
                                  $('#<%=Label414.ClientID%>').text(str1);
                              })
                              .trigger("change");
                        </script>

                           <select id="bowelMoves" name="bowelMoves" multiple="multiple" style="width: 125px">
                            <option>1 Quadrant</option>
                            <option>2 Quadrant</option>
                            <option>Hypo</option>
                            <option>Hyper</option>
                            <option>Normal</option>
                        </select>
                        <script type="text/javascript">
                            $("#bowelMoves")
                              .change(function () {
                                  var str2 = "";
                                  $("select option:selected").each(function () {
                                      str2 += $(this).text() + ", ";
                                  });
                                  $('#<%=Label418.ClientID%>').text(str2);
                              })
                              .trigger("change");
                        </script>
```